# google script, match column with other and grab next value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a google script to automate some calculations in a google spreadsheet.
I have several things in this sheet and what i need is, for all the date values i have on A column (between rows 3 and 20) i need to search on the column T (between rows 17 and 50) and when a date match i need to grab the value in the cell next to the data in column T.

Then with this sum i need to go to the B move one row down and substract that sum from the above cell.

example:
A
17/8/2017
18/8/2017
19/8/2017

B
100
empty
empty

T
empty
empty
18/8/2017
18/8/2017
18/8/2017
19/8/2017

U
empty
empty
5
5
2
1

After running the script B should be:
100
88
87

My code:

```
   function burnDown(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var completed = sheet.getRange(20, 20, 40);
   for(var i = 3; i<20;i++){
    for(var j = 1; i<50; j++){
      var sum = 0;
      if(data[i][0] == completed[j][0])
      {
        sum = sum + completed[j][20];
        Logger.log(completed[j][21] + "" + sum); 
    }
      j++;
  }
  i++;

}
}
```

I'm stuck at this point where I have to make the match but i'm getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 9, file "BurnDown"
Thanks,

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: sorry forgot it, added!

Comment: There's no values in completed

Answer (score 0):

No values in completed.  Perhaps you need a getValues() somewhere

```
 function burnDown()
 {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //var completed = sheet.getRange(20, 20, 40);//this is a range
  var completed = sheet.getRange(20,20,40).getValues();//this creates a 2d array of values
  for(var i = 3;i<20;i++)
  {
    for(var j = 1; j<50; j++)
    {
      var sum = 0;
      if(data[i][0]==completed[j][0])
      {
        sum=sum + completed[j][20];
        Logger.log(completed[j][21] + "" + sum);
      }
      //j++;//not sure why these are here the loop increments
    }
  //i++;//same question as above
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too but the error is the same.. i don't get why becuase if i go directly to data[20][20] out of the for i can read it..

Comment: data[20][20] is defined by the getDataRange() which is all of the data on the sheet.

Comment: Correct.. thats why i don't understand why i'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property "20" from undefined. (line 9, file "BurnDown"

Comment: around 50 (not always the same..but more or less) and columns from A to U but a lot of cells are empty

Comment: I just noticed that the stop condition for the second loop was i<50. I changed it to j<50;